# this is the error i am getting...Server Error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react";

function Login({ providers }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center bg-black min-h-screen w-full justify-center">
      <img className="w-52 mb-5" src="https://links.papareact.com/9xl" alt="" />

      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button
            className="bg-[#18D860] text-white p-5 rounded-full"
            onClick={() => signIn(provider.id, { callbackURL: "/" })}
          >
            Login with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const providers = await getProviders();

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're not getting providers into your login component. can you please check? and let us know what is the value you're getting ?

Comment: i am not getting any values i am getting an error unchecked runtime.lasterror: the message port close before a response was received, i am getting my providers from spotify-web-api-node ^5.0.2(version) and my next auth version is ^4.0.0-beta.7

Comment: As you're not getting any values. that's why you're unable to iterate over the loop. may be you should ask the another question for the question you're getting.

Comment: {"spotify":{"id":"spotify","name":"Spotify","type":"oauth","signinUrl":"https://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin/spotify","callbackUrl":"https://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/spotify"}}

Comment: if it helps api /auth /provider